# What is the git command xcode runs when clicking discard all changes?

Tags: git, xcode

noob here, I would like to understand what git command xcode actually runs when I click "Discard all changes" from the Source Control dropdown menu. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not use xcode, but from your description I guess it runs `git reset --hard HEAD` which is the ad-hoc command for this. This command reverts your tree state to the last commit state, loosing any tracked-but-uncommited work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What about untracked changes?

Comment: @AlexSu You sould use `git clean` to tidy up your tree. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean.